# UVA(820):Internet Bandwidth getting wrong answer?

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am trying to solve this [Problem](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=685&page=show_problem&problem=761) on UVA.The question is about finding the max-flow in the graph.I used Edmond-karp algorithm but I am continuously getting wrong answer.Can any one tell me what's wrong in my code ?
My code :

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define MX 1000000007
#define LL long long
#define ri(x) scanf("%d",&x)
#define rl(x) scanf("%lld",&x)
#define len(x) x.length()
#define FOR(i,a,n) for(int i=a;i<n;i++)
#define FORE(i,a,n) for(int i=a;i<=n;i++)
template<class T1> inline T1 maxi(T1 a,T1 b){return a>b?a:b;}
template<class T2> inline T2 mini(T2 a,T2 b){return a<b?a:b;}
int parent[101],G[101][101],rG[101][101];
bool bfs(int s,int t,int n)
{   
    bool vis[n+2];
    memset(parent,0,sizeof parent);
    memset(vis,0,sizeof vis);
    queue<int>Q;
    Q.push(s);
    vis[s]=true;
    while(!Q.empty())
    {
        int fnt=Q.front();
        Q.pop();
        for(int v=1;v<=n;v++)
        {
            if(!vis[v] and G[fnt][v]>0)
            {
                vis[v]=true;
                parent[v]=fnt;
                Q.push(v);
            }
        }
    }
    return vis[t];
}
int main()
{
    int n,tst=1;
    ri(n);
    while(n)
    {
        int s,t,c,flow=0;
        ri(s),ri(t),ri(c);
        FORE(i,1,c)
        {
            int x,y,z;
            ri(x),ri(y),ri(z);
            G[x][y]+=z;
            G[y][x]+=z;
        }
        while(bfs(s,t,n))
        {
            int path=9999999;
            for(int v=t;v!=s;v=parent[v])
            {
                int u=parent[v];
                path=mini(path,G[u][v]);
            }
            for(int v=t;v!=s;v=parent[v])
            {
                int u=parent[v];
                G[u][v]-=path;
                G[v][u]+=path;
            }
            flow+=path;
        }       
        printf("Network %d\nThe bandwidth is %d.\n\n", tst++, flow);
        ri(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: I hate problem statements on UVA because they usually don't give clear enough constraints. In this problem are you absolutely sure that the max flow can not overflow in? You are allowed to have multiple edges between a pair of nodes so in theory the max flow can overflow.

Comment: This isn't a debugging service. Narrow down the problem and ask something more specific. At least give us a case for which it fails.

Answer (score 0):

You push flow the other way around:

```
G[u][v]-=path;
G[v][u]+=path;
```

This should be:

```
G[u][v] += path;
G[v][u] -= path;
```

Also, I'm not sure about this part:

```
if(!vis[v] and G[fnt][v]>0)

[...]

path=mini(path,G[u][v]);
```

Because you are also allowed to take paths on which the flow is negative. You should not change `G`, which seems to be your capacities graph. Instead, you should have a matrix `F` that stores how much flow you send. Then your two conditions should be changed to:

```
if (!vis[v] && G[fnt][v] != F[fnt][v])

[...]

path = mini(path, G[u][v] - F[u][v])
```

And push flow on `F`, not `G`.

You seem to have thought about this since you declared a matrix `rG`, but you're never using it.

There might be other issues too. It's hard to tell without knowing what problems you're seeing.